# Can't run composer command on remote server

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, vps

Have a problem with install Symfony vendors on remote server (VPS), because after installation composer library by server administration, I have PHP Fatal error when I run it:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ErrorException: proc_close() has been disabled for security reasons in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:957
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Composer\Util\ErrorHandler::handle(2, 'proc_close() ha...', 'phar:///usr/loc...', 957, Array)
#1 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(957): proc_close(Resource id #252)
#2 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(753): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->getSttyColumns()
#3 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(714): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->getTerminalDimensions()
#4 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(648): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->getTerminalWidth()
#5 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(127): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->renderException(Object(ErrorException), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\StreamOutput))
#6 p in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php on line 957
```

Have `PHP 7.3.15`
`memory_limit => 1024M`

```
disable_functions => exec,system,passthru,shell_exec,proc_close,dl,popen,show_source,posix_kill,posix_mkfifo,posix_getpwuid,posix_setpgid,posix_setsid,posix_setuid,posix_setgid,posix_seteuid,posix_setegid,posix_uname => exec,system,passthru,shell_exec,proc_close,dl,popen,show_source,posix_kill,posix_mkfifo,posix_getpwuid,posix_setpgid,posix_setsid,posix_setuid,posix_setgid,posix_seteuid,posix_setegid,posix_uname
```

Maybe someone have any ideas?

Comment: Contact your host. Weirdly, they've disabled proc_close but not proc_open. Or if you've modified the php.ini, then you need to enable it.

Comment: You don't have to run composer on the remote server at all, you can run it locally and then just copy the resulting files over.

Comment: What **exactly** are you asking for? If that error message tells you that any function is disabled, you should either enable it or use any other way to achieve what you want to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways:

1. Contact your hosting source to allow you.
2. Push/Deploy the vendor from your local these way you don't need to run any composer command.

Answer (score 1):

If you are deploying in a shared cloud service the process won't work due to the limited resources available for your instance. I will advise you do the composer update or install on your development instance and transfer the files zipped to the host